# Python: Searching for an int in a list

Tags: python, list, search

Say I have this list

```
x = [1,2,3,1,5,1,8]
```

Is there a way to find every index that `1` is in the list?

Comment: What do you mean find? What output do you want? What have you tried?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure.  A list comprehension plus [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) should work:

```
[i for i, z in enumerate(x) if z == 1]
```

And the proof:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8]
>>> [i for i, z in enumerate(x) if z == 1]
[0, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Arrgh. I'm like 5 seconds to late... :)

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to python, how would I get it to print [0, 3, 5] using a print function?

Comment: Simple:  `print ([ i for i,z in enumerate(x) if z == 1 ])`

Comment: Thank you that did it. Is it possible to do this with x.index()?

Comment: @user1871081 -- Not easily.  `x.index` will give you the first occurrence, but getting subsequent occurrences would be a little more work.

Comment: If you don't mind could you show me how it would be done with `x.index`

Comment: @user1871081: re-read your notes from class and/or check the documentation for `list.index` (and a helpful hint: start a Python interpreter and type `help(list.index)`).

Answer (score 2):

The questioner asked for a solution using `list.index`, so here is one such solution:

```
def ones(x):
    matches = []
    pos = 0
    while True:
        try:
            pos = x.index(1, pos)
        except ValueError:
            break
        matches.append(pos)
        pos += 1
    return matches
```

It is somewhat more verbose than mgilson's solution, which I would consider to be more idiomatic Python.